# Account sign in mix up.. At&t Microsoft Windows 8.1 phone

Tags: 8.1, apps, facebook, lumia-denim

When my husband bought a new phone, I played some games on it to see if I liked it. I used the "Login using facebook" option. Now everytime he tries to play a game using the "Login using facebook" button, it goes to my account.. We've tried uninstalling and reinstalling all the games and facebook. Nothing seems to fix the problem. What do we do?

Comment: What games in particular? If you go to Facebook in Internet Explorer, who does it log in as?

Comment: I played Luckyo Casino and logged in using FB. Now every time he tries to log into anything using FB, it goes to my profile..

Answer (score 1):

Your Facebook account maybe linked with his Microsoft account or Xbox account.
First unlink your Facebook account, reinstall Facebook app (if you have since it integrates with your phone), restart the phone and play the games.

**Unlinking your Facebook from Microsoft account**

1. Login your account at https://profile.live.com
2. Click Manage
3. Locate your Facebook account
4. Click Edit
5. Click Remove this connection completely
6. Click Remove

**Unlinking your Facebook account from Xbox**

1. Open your Facebook on a computer
2. Go to settings page and navigate to apps
3. Locate Xbox live and remove the app

Here are some reference links, if you want more information

1. [Microsoft community - Unlink Facebook from Microsoft account](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/unlinking-facebook-account-in-outlookcom/1caa4c0f-4eef-4fef-ac84-f83909f80fe4?db=5)
2. [Xbox Forums - Unlink Facebook from Xbox](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/xba_console/how-to-unlink-my-xbox-live-account-from-facebook/e97df311-1afb-4f14-b690-addbe779fe9b).

Comment: You should summarize the content of the articles you linked to in case the links are later broken.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for the suggestion. I will improve my answer.

Comment: I played Luckyo Casino and logged in using FB. Now every time he tries to log into anything using FB, it goes to my profile..Thank You Kolappan Nathan! I'll try that:-)